# How can I send an email via PHPMAILER without SSL - port 25?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, starttls

I want to send an email without SSL using PHPMailer. I have enabled the debug mode so that I can check the details in the logs.

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(true); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = false; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
    $mail->Host = "mail.company.co.uk";
    $mail->Port = 25; // or 587
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "email@company.co.uk";
    $mail->Password = "password_of_username";
    $mail->SetFrom($email,$name);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $message;
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
```

This is giving an exception:

```
2018-09-28 10:04:27 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: EHLO localhost<br>
2018-09-28 10:04:27 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: STARTTLS<br>
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.<br>
2018-09-28 10:04:28 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: QUIT<br>
2018-09-28 10:04:28 <br>
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting<br>
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You've based your code on an old example, which doesn't help. You can't see what's going on because you've only used `1` for `SMTPDebug`; set it to `2`.

Your mail server is advertising that it supports STARTTLS on port 25, so PHPMailer is using it automatically. You can disable encryption entirely by doing this:

```
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;
```

However, I'd recommend not doing this; fix your TLS config instead. You probably need to update your local CA certificate bundle - see the troubleshooting guide for more details.

One time that doing this is appropriate is when you are sending to `localhost`; you can't get a certificate for `localhost`, but there is no security risk as it's all local, so disabling TLS is fine. Of course, your mail server should not be advertising that it supports STARTTLS on localhost, but that's a separate problem!

Comment: $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false; <--- this did the job. SSL one was working fine till if fix the SSL issue. I want to keep the email form going.

Comment: I read your comments on a number of web pages. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: $mail->SMTPAuth = false;